# How to convert 1/(s + a) to 1/a(1+s/a)

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression like 1/(s + a) and now I want to display it in the form 1/a * 1/(1+s/a) or 1/(a(1+s/a)).
With display I don't need to display it exactly as the format but what I want to see is the factor 1+s/a.

**Update:**
I want to make the form 1 + s/a appeared so I know that the expression has a pole at frequency a (rad/s).

This expression is simple so the method may not be necessary but for other more complex expression, I would like to know if there is a way to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Look in to TraditionalForm

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to identify the poles, you can get them from an algebraic function and some transcendental functions with `Solve`.
This can be helpful when, for instance, the value of `a` is unknown beforehand and needs to be computed from the result of another computation.

```
fn = 1/(s + a);
s /. Solve[1/fn == 0, s]
(*  {-a}  *)
```

If the output-formatting is important, then the poles can be used as follows:

```
fn2 = s/(a b c + a b s + a c s + b c s + a s^2 + b s^2 + c s^2 + s^3);
poles = s /. Solve[1/fn2 == 0, s]
Simplify[fn2 * Apply[Times, (poles - s)/poles]] / Apply[Times, (1 - s/poles)]
(*
  {-a, -b, -c}
  s/(a b c (1 + s/a) (1 + s/b) (1 + s/c))
*)
```

*Alternatives:*

[`TransferFunctionPoles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionPoles.html) can be used, too.

```
poles = Flatten@TransferFunctionPoles[TransferFunctionModel[fn2, s]]
(*  {-a, -b, -c}  *)
```

From internal `Integrate` functions (subject to change without notice):

```
Quiet@Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 1}];  (* loads Integrate`NLtheoremDump`ExceptionLocusNP *)
Block[{Integrate`NLtheoremDump`$SingPoints = {}},
 Integrate`NLtheoremDump`ExceptionLocusNP[fn2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
(*  {-a, -b, -c}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split them in `Numerator` and `Denominator`

```
f = 1/(s + a);
x1 = (Numerator[f]/a)
x2 = (Denominator[f]/a) // Expand

x1/x2
```

> $\frac{1}{a}$
>
> $1+\frac{s}{a}$
>
> $\frac{1}{a \left(1+\frac{s}{a}\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

How about introducing normalized variables? (There are many letters to pick from; see [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).)

```
expr = 1/(s + a);
Factor[expr /. s -> \[ScriptS] a]
```

> `1/(a (1 + \[ScriptS]))`